# How to append a string to where clause in APEX Interactive Report SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am a newbee in Apex and I am using apex 5.1.3. I am creating a report through sql query and where clause of the query should be dynamic which needs be taken from another table column. On page load i loaded this where condition string from table and set that as page item **:P5_NEW**

I tried like this:

**select * from EMPLOYEES where :P5_NEW**

Page item **:P5_NEW** contains the string which should be appended to where clause. But apex throws error **ORA-00920: invalid relational operator**.

Can some one please advice how I can append a string to where clause in APEX report query?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be very concerned about the sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P5_NEW (well, why not `P5_WHERE`?) should be a Text field with "Submit when Enter pressed" set to YES. It should contain the **whole WHERE clause**, including the `WHERE` keyword. If you put it as you did, you'll get the *ORA-00936 missing expression error*.

Query would then look like this:

```
select * 
from employees
&P5_WHERE.    --> pay attention! Ampersand (&) followed by field name
              --> followed by a dot (.)
```

What next? Nothing ... run the page & enjoy. If you enter something like
`WHERE department_id = 10` into the P5_WHERE field and hit Enter key, output should change.