# Oracle Apex 5.0: populate a IR with WHERE IN clause based on page item

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I am try to set up a page that contains:

- a page item (*P16_INPUT*) where users paste a list of IDs (on separate lines)
- an interactive report (*output*) that should be populated based on the IDs

to achieve this I have added an intermediate hidden page item (*P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE*) where I convert the input text (on different lines) into a comma-separated text strings with single quotes.

Example:
User enters in *P16_INPUT*:
*RTR123 

RTR456*

A Dynamic action calls an (overly complicated) PL/SQL expression that populates
*P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE*:

```
declare
l_in varchar(4000);
l_int varchar(4000);
l_out varchar(4000);
begin 
l_in := :P16_INPUT;
l_int := replace(l_in,Chr(13),''',''');
l_out := '''' || l_int || '''';
l_out := replace(l_out,Chr(10));
l_out := replace(l_out,Chr(9));
:P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE := l_out;
end;
```

which produces:
*'RTR123','RTR456'*

The dynamic action refreshes also the *output* IR, which is based on the following SQL statement:

```
 select t1.id ,t1.b_seq , t1.s_seq, t1.back_seq
          from v_export t1
         where t1.id in (:P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE);
```

But I always get back an empty table.

If I only enter 1 ID in *P16_INPUT* and skip the intermediate *P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE*, the IR is correctly populated with 1 row of results.

Comment: Not sure what best way around this would be but what I believe is happening is that it is treating :P16_INPUT_INTERMEDIATE as a string so wrapping it in single quotes.... so a single line sipping the intermediate becomes 'RTR123' but the multi line becomes something like '''RTR123'',''RTR456''' (adds single quotes to beginning and end then escapes interior single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how exactly to do this as I havent worked with it much, but what you are trying to do is dynamic SQL, an SQL query that is compiled on runtime.
Gl with it

Comment: I managed to solve this by including the entire WHERE clause in a page item as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308429/how-to-append-a-string-to-where-clause-in-apex-interactive-report-sql